# Using Angular 9 Material Styles Locally

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am implementing very basic tables following the examples given in the official [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

In those examples, the tables have nice styling which is seemingly localized to each sample table.  The main style I want to use is mat-elevation-z8 (from what I can tell).  Unfortunately, when I embed that table in my page it styles the entire page, all the way up to the body.  Here is a stackblitz which shows what I mean:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5oe5jz

The divs above and below the table are styled to match the table.  I want the table to be styled in isolation as in the samples.  Is my only option to go override every property I don't want to be affected by Material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You don't need to override every property, but you just use material `CSS` classes where you require otherwise don't add the classes.

2) For example in your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5oe5jz) link the page is looking with material design, because you applied class `'mat-app-background basic-container'` to the `div` in your `index.html` file. so that the entire page is looking with material design.

3) Remove that `mat-app-background basic-container` from `index.html` file, and use material CSS classes to for tables only.

4) I have just updated the `index.html` file for your reference. [check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5oe5jz-x2cyi9?file=src/index.html)